# Best approach to correlate images, based on their tags

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was trying to tackle an ML problem with tensor flow, but im not sure what algorithm should I use. I have tagged images on my dataset. When a new image comes on, i want the to correlate the images I have, based on the tags. Where should I start? O.o

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by correlate the images? Are you attempting to cluster the images based on their tags?

If so, you could train an encoder that runs over your images, produces a feature vector and cluster those feature vectors based on their image tags. So for example, consider you had multiple images of tags: cars & cats. You could run an encoder (consisting of convolutional layers), flatten the final layer to get a feature vector and run a clustering algorithm like K-means (with K=2, since you only have 2 tags -cars & cats).

Depending on the size and nature of the images in your dataset you might have to play around with the encoder architecture, collect more data, use alternate clustering algorithms etc.

In the event your image feature vector can belong to multiple classes and you would like to return possible tags, you'll have to opt for soft clustering algorithms such as GMMs (Gaussian Mixture Models) or [FCMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering) (Fuzzy C Means). These algorithms don't specifically output class but outputs a class score for each data point. So if you want the top 5 tags of a new image, you could:

- Run an encoder to get a feature vector
- Perform soft clustering on the feature vectors
- Get the 5 highest scoring classes

Comment: I think it is something like that, yes. For example, lets say I'm on some social media and I share a photo, which has some tags. These are not identification tags, its more like those # things you see on twitter. For example, if I posted a car photo I could tag it with "car, electric, tesla". Now i want to see suggestions related to the photo I just shared. Is this really image clustering?

Comment: Ah I see. I would still say this can be framed as a clustering problem. You'll have to switch to soft k means, GMMs, FCMs (Fuzzy C Means) since an image can be a part of multiple classes (i.e. have different tags) and you'll want to quantify that. I'll elaborate my answer.